# How to output my object in array with another form?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question really bother me, currently I have an array with below form(the input array),

```
var randomstring = require("randomstring");
const random = randomstring.generate();
     const input = [
      { key: 'shop', value: '100' },
      { key: 'TradeNo', value: random },
      { key: 'TradeDate', value: '2017/10/06 02:11:23' },
      { key: 'Type', value: 'aio' },
      { key: 'Amount', value: '100' },
      { key: 'Desc', value: 'Credit' },
      { key: 'ItemName', value: 'MacBook' },
      { key: 'URL', value: 'https://www.facebook.com/' },
      { key: 'Payment', value: 'Credit' },
      { key: 'Type', value: '1' },
    ];
```

Now I want to console.log below form so that I can use this form to run some test in the postman, the type would be like:

```
[
{"key":"shop","value":"100"},
{"key":"TradeNo","value":"random"},//this random still means the same random string
{"key":"TradeDate","value":"2017/10/06 02:11:23"},{"key":"Type","value":"aio"},
{"key":"Amount","value":"100"},
{"key":"Desc","value":"Credit"},
{"key":"ItemName","value":"MacBook"},{"key":"URL","value":"https://www.facebook.com/"},{"key":"Payment","value":"Credit"},
{"key":"Type","value":"1"}
]
```

Which means I need to add " " in each part and I do not understand how to handle it, what can I try to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: `JSON.stringify(input)` ---> convert into its JSON string format

Comment: Couldn't you just use `JSON.stringify(const);`?

Comment: Sorry for asking this question, I did not know it could be solved that easily, thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to convert the object it into its [JSON string](https://www.json.org). In Javascript use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method to generate the corresponding JSON string.

```
JSON.stringify(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want your object in JSON format. With that in mind you could use `JSON.stringify()` as so:

```js
const input = [
  { key: 'shop', value: '100' },
  { key: 'TradeNo', value: 'random' },
  { key: 'TradeDate', value: '2017/10/06 02:11:23' },
  { key: 'Type', value: 'aio' },
  { key: 'Amount', value: '100' },
  { key: 'Desc', value: 'Credit' },
  { key: 'ItemName', value: 'MacBook' },
  { key: 'URL', value: 'https://www.facebook.com/' },
  { key: 'Payment', value: 'Credit' },
  { key: 'Type', value: '1' },
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(input));
```